# How to run Spring Boot app with JMS concurrently on Tomcat server?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, messaging, spring-jms

I am creating a Spring Boot application with JMS. I want to run the application locally with the embedded Tomcat server so that I can call a RestController and post a message to a queue.

Here is the flow that I'm trying to implement:

***Postman -> RestController -> Service -> Put message to queue.***

However, when I start the application, I get the following error:

```
Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8082 was already in use.
```

I believe that the issue is related to the Tomcat server and JMS competing for resources, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to configure the embedded Tomcat server and JMS to run concurrently? Or maybe suggest a different approach I should take?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was cause by the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJmsApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsApplication.class, args);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsApplication.class,
        args);
  }

}
```

So I removed the following line and the application ran successfully:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsApplication.class,
    args);
```